# Getting Response 500 python

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-500, python-requests-html

I want to get access from this website https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/ but I am getting 500 error using requests I have also try proxies Api to get 200 response but still getting same response

Here is my code:

```
import requests
# headers = {
#     'authority': 'www.truepeoplesearch.com',
# 'method': 'GET',
# 'path': '/?__cf_chl_rt_tk=yRTk.U51_2F3gk2zvxX_GLO5MgGmfwXsQeScGiGloJM-1637358329-0-gaNycGzNCpE',
# 'scheme': 'https',
# 'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
# 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
# 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
# 'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
# 'cookie':' __cf_bm=jDWsHwlBvdk987UFEnrW63LelWWz03HXgZg3jDPaYY0-1637358168-0-AeyRiZHGcxyaD4j/7LGGq1aVmo5sBj/qmFX58OY4gfcUtvfzaG1exKf4HiYNNAlSaqm6LZ3MWB2UBgaOeIugrxA=; aegis_uid=26435771721; aegis_tid=direct; _ga=GA1.2.1056913930.1637358268; _gid=GA1.2.364813628.1637358268; cf_chl_prog=F13; cf_chl_rc_m=7',
# 'referer': 'https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/?__cf_chl_rt_tk=yRTk.U51_2F3gk2zvxX_GLO5MgGmfwXsQeScGiGloJM-1637358329-0-gaNycGzNCpE',
# 'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"',
# 'sec-ch-ua-mobile':' ?0',
# 'sec-ch-ua-platform':' "Windows"',
# 'sec-fetch-dest':' document',
# 'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
# 'sec-fetch-site':' same-origin',
# 'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
# 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'
# }
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {'api_key': 'dd6a50aba760cc67e0276d840a7989cd', 'url': 'https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/'}
r = requests.get('http://api.scraperapi.com', params=payload, headers= headers)
print(r)
```

I have try both headers but didn't get 200 response, Anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe problem is website because i cannot connect right now.

Comment: its only work on United States

Comment: have you tried it with other urls? if the problem persists the docs [link](https://www.scraperapi.com/documentation/), indicate that "ScraperAPI will retry failed requests for up to 60 seconds to try and get a ... response from the target url before responding with a 500" and thus recommends "Note: To avoid timing out your request before the API has had a chance to complete all retries, remember to set your timeout to 60 second"

Comment: Yeah I have tried more than 2 other website its working perfectly. any idea how to exceed the time out session?